# Python: Iterating through q.collections.table

Tags: python

I used Dan Nugents' Python library (http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api) and successfully got the table object, i.e.,  after submitting a query to the database. However, how can I iterate through every single row of the object?

Let's say the table object is "results". I tried:

```
for i in results.keys():
    print results[i]
```

However, it says "raise ValueError". Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly which library are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the link: Dan Nugents' http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api

Comment: Try `for result in results.values(): print result`?

Comment: File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\q\collections.py", line 290, in values
    raise ValueError
ValueError

Answer (score 0):

From this section (4. Example of sending / receiving data and tables. of [this](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api)). You seem to be getting  a list of dict's(`results` is not a dictionary). Try printing them as

```
for result in results:
    print result
```